# How to customize Orchard Theme or how to add some item in orchard homepage?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I need to learn more about orchard
for example I need to add some item to orchard homepage and more customize it's homepage 
and them how to add sidebar to orchard theme ?
or how we can create a mvc web app in vs and select it as orchard theme ?
I ask about the best cms for mvc and they said me it's orchard in asp.net forum but they don't answer my question about how to customize it's theme and link me here to asking my question .
I wrok with wordpress and now I want to work and continue with asp.net .
please help me how can I add some more item to orchard homepage and more customize it's homepage ?
THanks 
Great Regards :
Raha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the orchard website and follow the guide on how to [create a theme](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme). This will allow you to easily create alternative views for orchards default rendering of parts of the page, or "shapes". Although if your unaware of how to edit the theme then that tells me you don't know much about how Orchard works and how powerful it is. I recommend reading through the [Orchard Documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/) to learn about how Orchard works, in particular in your case alternatives and widgets.

For example, to have a persistent sidebar you could use a html widget with (or without) and alternative to code up something cool and add it to the default layer (or even base it on roles if your adventures with modules). Or if it's going to be a menu just stick a menu widget in the homepage and use alternatives to give it attributes so you can style it in CSS. There are several ways to achieve what you want.

But to directly answer your final question (Which is a bit ambiguous) you need to add widgets to a specific layer in order to "add items" to a page. The main content though is not added through widgets though (its the page itself that is the content).

Comment: in orchard website there isn't any useful tut and helpful documentation to create a professional theme . the simple theme that is in orchard web I created . that's not complete . I need more help . for Example as I said I need to add a slideshow to orchard homepage . how can I add this . slideshow isn't in orchard widget . so we must edit it with coding . now which file is home page to add slideshow code to it ? there are a lot of question about orchard that there isn't any forums to answer them ? for example I asked which file is orchard homepage in about 14 forums but nobody answered me yet

Comment: If you want a professional theme, download a  theme (eg. Bootstrap) from the Orchard gallery. Open it in VS in the orchard solution and look at how it works, and how you can edit it for your case. You should be able to see how the homepage is generated from that. If not, your not thinking about orchard correctly, and as I mentioned above you need to learn orchard inner workings first. Pages are created extremely dynamically, with one page comprising of several CSHTML documents that are called by shapes.

In terms of a slideshow, look into the gallery for something.